# Are there any major loopholes with having my handler bypass security for certain API methods?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API service that contains methods that all require security that is processed via logic implemented within a CustomAuthenticationHandler handler using the following:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //Security Logic

    //Return Task
}
```

However I have a method that I want publically exposed that does *not* require security. I'm trying to prevent having a separate service just for this one method that I do not require any security information. The following is how I've done this, *and it works*:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

  if (request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath == "/api/MyPublicNoSecurityNeededMethod")
       return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task => task.Result);

    //Security Logic

    //Return Task
}
```

Thus I essentially return early and never go through the security logic. I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with this approach or if there is a more secure way of handling this need? If the answer is URLs can be spoofed, so doing that method of looking at the request could open up a backdoor, etc. that's what I'm trying to determine. I just don't want to expose my other methods to vulnerabilities if the way I've implemented this is not the correct way about solving this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use of HttpMessageHandler is incorrect. The handler should only authenticate the client and set the current principal in Thread.CurrentPrincipal and optionally in HttpContext.Current.User if the Web Api is hosted in ASP.NET. Then, the framework provides attributes that you can use to define authorization rules on the action such as the [AuthorizeAttribute] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes. Those attribute rely on the Current Principal to perform authorization.

```
public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "hello " + User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    public class HelloWorldAnonymousController : ApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "hello anonymous";
        }
    }
```

Authorize specifies that the action requires an authenticated user. AllowAnonymous does not require any authenticated user. About your question, there is nothing wrong with having actions that does not require authentication.

Comment: I actually did everything you state (I'm setting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with the `IIdentity` instance). However I added this to my Global.asax (`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomAuthenticationHandler());`) so the each API method did not require the `[Authorize]` attribute. Then I disallow access to the service early on if authentication is not valid. I din't want each Controller method to have to handle it's own authentication/authorization since the rules were the same for all methods (except this one that my OP is about).

Comment: So you can set the AuthorizeFilte globally so all the actions are secured by default, and override the actions that you want to have with anonymous access with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute

Comment: Ok I see where you are going with this. So basically 1. my approach *was* incorrect. 2. If I move to using `[Authorize]` attributes, how do I intervene to provide more to the client than `Authorization has been denied for this request`, but rather something like: `Authorization has been denied for this request. Your IP does not match the account credentials you provided`?

Comment: You can derive the AuthorizeAttibute and add all the detail you want to the response. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Yes makes sense. Do you have an example of doing this or seen a blog link on doing this?

Comment: One other thing, look at your sample on your blog which is almost identical to mine.http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2013/02/25/message-handlers-per-route-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx I need to remove the following line `return ChallengeResponse(request);` that challenges for authentication headers if they do not exist, as some of my methods will now be decorated with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. I can't challenge for credentials if I have methods that don't require them. Is this the way you would go about it, remove the challenge for credentials?

Comment: If the case of my last comment is true and the proper way of solving the issue, than I'm good to go. I don't challenge for the header credentials if they do not exist. The methods deny access via `[Authorize]` attribute, because logic to build up `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with the `IIdentity` never occurred. All my tests seem to be working and I removed the code from my OP. I just want your confirmation on if removing the challenge for credentials and allowing the methods to be the fail safe for authorization is acceptable?

Comment: Can you confirm/deny on my last 2 comments if this is correct so that I may have the answer and mark your suggestions?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. The challenge must be sent only after executing base.SendAsync(..) when the HttpStatus code is unauthorized. base.SendAsync will try to execute the action, so if the framework finds an AllowAnonymous attribute, it will work. Otherwise, the framework will return a 401 that your handler can catch to optionally return a challenge. Makes sense ? Thanks

Comment: Yes it does. Right now I'm not going to exercise the option to have the credentials challenged but rather just return the 401. However it's good to know I could use a handler to return the challenge if needed. I have this working well and wanted to make sure I was on the right track. Thanks for your suggestions and help.